# Yii2. Button does not work after Pjax reload

Tags: button, yii2, reload, pjax

I have a button wrapped into Pjax in Yii2.

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax15', 'options' => ['style' => 'display: inline;']]);
                echo Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true"></span>', [
                        'value' => Url::to(['vote/create', 'id'=>$model->id]),
                        'class' => 'linkbutton',
                        'id'=>'createVote'.$model->id,
                        'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                        'title'=> 'Assign',
                        'onfocus' => 'blur();'
                     ]);
Pjax::end();
```

I reload it from JS as following:

```
       $.pjax.reload({container:'#pjax15', timeout: 5000});
```

But after first reload the button does nothing if I click it. What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Show your full code or you are including `Pjax::begin()` two times.

Like if you have call Pjax in `index.php`  then don't need to call this in _form.php or other file. so make sure you include `Pajx::begin()` only once.

Answer (score 0):

Just do bind to body.
    $("body .myButton).click (function(){
        //
    });